# Error in customising Toast message

Tags: android

I am customising the Toast message with the following code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        textView.setText("Textview as Toast");

        Toast toastView = new Toast(this);
        toastView.setView(textView);
        toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toastView.show();

    }
```

The problem I am facing is that , when I am adding my own background color to the TextView , its not taking . Its taking the colours which are defined at the Color class.

Kindly provide your inputs/suggestions.

Comment: if you change text color, does it take?

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass your color like this 0xff888888 format

Comment: Defining in the color.xml  <color name="orange">#BA862B</color>  & then adding as textView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.orange);